# How to reduce poly without losing the shape

Tags: mesh

I have this mesh and I want to reduce the polys, or in this case the amount of excessive faces/edges, but when I use the option clean > limited dissolve this happens

[image]

[image]

Could someone please help me with this , its for the sims 4 game.

Comment: Reduce polys in the other direction. There seem to be a lot of useless loops densely packed perpendicular to the marked edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Decimate modifier shown below:

[image]

Comment: done sorry im new here too !